# MYSQL UTF8 Accents insensitive search

Tags: mysql, select, utf-8, collation

I need to do an accent insensitive search at my database.
The table collation is UTF8.

At my table I have this data.

**mysql> select * from categoria;**

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| EletrÃ´nicos   |
| InformÃ¡tica   |
| AcessÃ³rios    |
+------+
```

I would like to do a search without accents and be able to return the data.

I'm trying to do this search:

**Select name from categoria where name like '%eletronicos%'**

But the query didn't return any row!

Someone knows how can I do that?

**Explaining better**

The problem is that the data were stored on database encoded as UTF8.

```
**Correct word with accent:** Eletrônicos
**Stored at database like:** EletrÃ´nicos
**Searched word without accents** Eletronicos
```

Best, Flavio

Comment: The where condition in the query should be `name LIKE '%eletronicos%'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to switch your collation to utf8_general_ci, [who is case and accent insensitive](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748)

Comment: Hello Syneo, please see my edit **Explaining better**, in this case just change the collation will not work.